# Xcode Firebase Authentication not working

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication, firebase-analytics

My Firebase authentication is not working. Here is the log from the console:

```
2017-06-02 08:12:18.928 Study M8[67744] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS003016] Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
2017-06-02 08:12:19.544 Study M8[67744:2637901] Simulator user has requested new graphics quality: 10
2017-06-02 08:12:19.576 Study M8[67744] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS005000] The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/analytics-adsupport
2017-06-02 08:12:19.619 Study M8[67744] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023007] Firebase Analytics v.4000000 started
2017-06-02 08:12:19.621 Study M8[67744] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/dev3ec8a1cb4)
2017-06-02 08:12:19.748 Study M8[67744] <Warning> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS032003] iAd framework is not linked. Search Ad Attribution Reporter is disabled.
2017-06-02 08:12:19.755 Study M8[67744] <Notice> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023012] Firebase Analytics enabled
2017-06-02 08:12:20.454 Study M8[67744:2638259] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-02 08:12:20.456 Study M8[67744:2638259] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-02 08:12:20.573 Study M8[67744:2637901] <Firebase/Network/ERROR> Encounter network error. Code, error: -1200, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x60800004e610 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-02 08:12:20.576 Study M8[67744] <Error> [Firebase/Core][I-NET901017] <Firebase/Network/ERROR> Encounter network error. Code, error: -1200, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x60800004e610 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-02 08:12:20.577 Study M8[67744] <Error> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901017] Encounter network error. Code, error: -1200, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000052720 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:1030084793656:ios:2caba89d2a97a5b1?platform=ios&app_instance_id=7B84A3F451A04EBEAB26BE84DE23D1D4&gmp_version=4000, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:1030084793656:ios:2caba89d2a97a5b1?platform=ios&app_instance_id=7B84A3F451A04EBEAB26BE84DE23D1D4&gmp_version=4000, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-02 08:12:20.580 Study M8[67744] <Error> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000020] Error posting to Clearcut: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x60800004e610 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}, with Status Code: 0
2017-06-02 08:12:28.627210+1000 Study M8[67744:2637901] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/jack.staples/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A86AAB47-B72B-41D0-9FE3-6BAA9F7097ED/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-06-02 08:12:28.634587+1000 Study M8[67744:2637901] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2017-06-02 08:12:37.313 Study M8[67744:2638259] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
2017-06-02 08:12:37.317 Study M8[67744] <Error> [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS901017] Encounter network error. Code, error: -1200, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x60800024dc20 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:1030084793656:ios:2caba89d2a97a5b1?platform=ios&app_instance_id=7B84A3F451A04EBEAB26BE84DE23D1D4&gmp_version=4000, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://app-measurement.com/config/app/1:1030084793656:ios:2caba89d2a97a5b1?platform=ios&app_instance_id=7B84A3F451A04EBEAB26BE84DE23D1D4&gmp_version=4000, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-06-02 08:12:37.324 Study M8[67744:2638259] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)
```

If anyone has any idea whats going on the help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this lines to your **plist file:**

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
  <dict>  
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>  
  <true/>  
  </dict>
```

Comment: This fixed that problem but now I get an HTTP load error to googleapis.com